# How to incorporate dividends while calculating annual return of a Stock

Tags: stocks, dividends, rate-of-return

When we say that the average annualized return of a stock XYZ over the last 5 yrs is 7%, how do we factor in dividends?

For example, let us say, if XYZ was at 100$, and at the end of year 1, it was 105 ;

at the end of year 2, it was 110  ;

at the end of year 3, it was 115 ;

at the end of year 4, it was 120 ;

at the end of year 5,it was 125.

And each quarter, it paid a dividend of 1$/share, then what will be the average annualized return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply add the dividend to the stock price when calculating its annual return.

So for year one, instead of

```
(105-100)/(100) = 5%
```

it would be

```
(105+4-100)/(100) = 9%
```

Comment: Thanks, did not realize it was that simple.

Comment: This is only an approximation if the dividends come quarterly.  You need to compute quarterly returns in this manner and then use them to get the annual returns.  R_annual = (1+R1)(1+R2)(1+R3)(1+R4) -1

Comment: Yes, but if you're going to incorporate time value into your dividends then you need to know both the time horizon and the dividend pay date

Comment: ... and next step would be to factor in the tax rate so your back-tests yield real-life results.  For instance, I would run the full $4 dividend on tax-shielded accounts, but normal accounts I'd use $3.60 for an after tax ROI.  8.6% = (105+(4*.9)-100)/(100)